# How can I interact with Users via the ElementAPI?

Tags: users, current-user, plugin-elementapi

I am attempting to use the [ElementAPI](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) to check if a user is logged in or not. I've used the ElementAPI before to check/get entries for a given section, but never for user-based entries.

Here is my `elementapi.php` file:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'user/current.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'User',
            'criteria' => [
                'foo' => 'bar', // Not sure what to do here.
            ],
            'transformer' => function (EntryModel $user) {
                // Not sure about this either...
                if ($user->isCurrent) {
                    return [
                        'status' => true
                    ];
                } else {
                    return [
                        'status' => false
                    ];
                }
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

I'm getting to the plugin, but It really is not happy with what I'm giving it:

```
Argument 1 passed to Craft\ConfigService::Craft\{closure}() must be an instance of Craft\EntryModel, instance of Craft\UserModel given
```

Pretty sure it has something to do with the criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```php
function (EntryModel $user)
```

to

```php
function (UserModel $user)
```

You were passing in a user to a function that’s expecting an EntryModel. That’s the reason for the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you, Brandon and Luke. I knew I wasn't passing in the correct class... just wasn't sure what the correct usage was. This gets me back on the road!